Second World War Movie - Around '90
The movie is set during the second world war, in Greece. At the time, Italy and Germany were allied and after the conquest of an island two companies, one Italian and one German, were occupying with no more bloodshed and becoming friends. An Italian officer met a Greek girl and they quickly fell in love. Until one day, Italy changed side and since Germans heard of the announce before Italians (who didn't get communication at all) the latter were captured and killed. All except the officer, who was left wonder by his German peer who didn't have the guts to finish him because of their previous friendship.

Captain Corelli's Mandolin? I don't remember it all, but that could be it.

@Larme That was my thought too. You should post that as an answer and I'll give you an up-vote.

@Larme I'll up vote too because that sounds like it

That was my first thought too, without even having read the book or watched the movie ;)

yes, it's the right one! As Erik said add it as answer so I can close it! Thank you guys!

The answer is Captain Corelli's Mandolin
Synopsis on IMDB:

In 1941, Italy allies with Germany and ruthlessly conquers the much
  weaker country of Greece. On a remote Greek island, an Italian
  artillery garrison is established to maintain order. One Italian
  officer, Captain Corelli, adopts an attitude of mutual co-existence
  with the Greeks and engages in such activities as music festivals and
  courting the daughter of a local doctor. In 1943, however, after Italy
  surrenders to the Allies and changes sides in the war, Captain Corelli
  must defend the Greek island against a German invasion.

It's based on the book (Captain) Corelli's Mandolin of Louis de Bernières.
Trailer:




This video is unavailable
